# How to collect data from different subdirectories containing excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a main directory containing multiple subdirectories which again have excel files. I want to loop through the directories and read the excel files into a pandas dataframe and make a **collated** dataframe containing the data from all the excel files.
The code that I've written so far gets the excel files from the subdirectories but I am unable to get them into a dataframe. Can someone help me with the same. The code that I've written so far is as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
fin = pd.DataFrame()
rootdir = 'C:\\Divyam Projects\\ISB Work\\NHB Data'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        fin.append(df)

print(fin)
```

In the above code I'm trying to declare a dataframe 'fin' and then trying to append it with the information from different excel files. The code is giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Divyam Projects\ISB Work\NHB Data\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\divya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 859, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 874, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 928, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 915, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2070, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 3
```

The sample header for the excel file is
[image: Sample header]

Comment: The problem is not the `fin` dataframe. You have a problem with the csv separator or quote. Is it possible to see a header of one or two cvs files, please?

Comment: Sure @Corralien... I have included it in the question above

Comment: Open your file with nodepad or another editor. I would like to see your file as plain text with separator and quoting